# Traer etiquetas desde MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

hola buenas tengo un problema ya que guardo un texto con etiquetas en mi base de datos y al imprimirlas me muestra el texto con las etiquetas y mi sitio no las reconoce adjunto imágenes de ejemplo

Estoy utilizando Laravel 5.5

[image: Es asi como lo tengo guardado en mi base de datos]

[image: Asi me las muestra en el view]

Queria preguntar si existe alguna forma que al momentro de traerlas al view me reconozca las etiquetas.
Este es mi VIEW

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
   <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
       <div class="ibox-title">
           <h5><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> Preguntas Frecuentes
           </h5>
       </div>
       <div class="ibox-content m-b-sm">
               <tbody>
               @foreach($preguntasfrecuentes as $preguntafrecuente)
                    <details>
                       <summary>{{$preguntafrecuente->pregunta}}</summary>
                       <p>{{$preguntafrecuente->respuesta}}</p>
                    </details>
               @endforeach
               </tbody>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Esta es mi funcion//CONTROLADOR

```
public function pfrecuentes()
{
    $preguntafrecuente=Preguntas_Frecuentes::all();
    return view(GetDiseno('admin.pacientes.preguntasfrecuentes'))
    ->with('preguntasfrecuentes',$preguntafrecuente);

}
```

Comment: Renato. Puedes escribir tu código PHP y la vista HTML en la que pretendes escribirlo por favor?

Comment: @PakLeiChong Ya amigo listo!

Comment: estas usando laravel ?

Comment: @DiegoAvila Sii!, perdon po no especificarlo enseguida lo hago

Comment: saludos revisa esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253979/laravel-5-display-html-with-blade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entonces tendrias que mostrar el resultado de esta forma

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
   <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
       <div class="ibox-title">
           <h5><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> Preguntas Frecuentes
           </h5>
       </div>
       <div class="ibox-content m-b-sm">
               <tbody>
               @foreach($preguntasfrecuentes as $preguntafrecuente)
                    <details>
                       <summary>{!! $preguntafrecuente->pregunta !!}</summary>
                       <p>{!! $preguntafrecuente->respuesta !!}</p>
                    </details>
               @endforeach
               </tbody>
       </div>
   </div>
```

[Documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#displaying-data)

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS ME SIRVIÓ!.

Answer (score 1):

Según la documentación de Laravel puedes utilizar la siguiente forma:

> {!! $text !!}

Entonces, creo que sería algo como

```
<p>{!! $preguntafrecuente->respuesta !!}</p>
```

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS ME SIRVIO